# About struct and arrays (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, 3d

I'm trying to create code using a struct and a pointer, for example:

```
struct Vector()
{ double x,y,z;};
```

`struct vector *p[][][]`. I need a 3d parameter which have x,y and z coordinates for a molecular simulation.
The problem is: I want to run in Ubuntu's terminal and give the values of sample size using argc argv on terminal.

So I ask you guys: Can I create a struct array? I believe this will solve my problem.

Comment: What problem?  Note that this is not a site dedicated to teaching C.

Comment: Is your problem related with the structs creation or about the usage of argc and argv from terminal?

Comment: So, i want to create a dinamic struct vector p[x][y][z] for example, where i put x, y and z values in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the struct definition you provided ( `struct Vector()` ) as an example is not a struct definition.

But yes, you can use `int argc, char *argv[]` to read the command line for user input.
Then you can use something as simple as

```
If(argc != 2) {
    printf("usage error, exiting");
    return 0;
}

int array_size = atoi(argc[1]);
```

Then for example you can easily create an array of struct by declaring a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct {
     double x;
     double y;
     double z
} MOLECULE;

MOLECULE molArray[array_size];//from user input - each of array_size instances contains x,y,z members.
```

There are several ways to instantiate a pointer reference to this example struct, i.e.

```
MOLECULE *pMolecule = malloc(array_size)*sizeof(*molecule));
```

Or

```
MOLECULE *pMolecule = {0};
MOLECULE molecule = {1.0,2.0,3.0};//simple sample of data

pMolecule = &modlecule;//pointer pointing to area in memory containing instance of MOLECULE
```

Note that with an array of struct, it becomes impracticable to use user input to populate the many members, reading that information from a file, or a database is probably best.

If you provide more details, this answer can do the same.  Just flag me in a comment

***EDIT*** To address question in comments *"...but how it would if I needed a MOLECULE molArray[x][y][z] ? and x,y,z is a dynamic value which I enter in the beginning of the program?"*:

Using [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) allows a way to dynamically defined sizes of objects when the sizes needed are not known until run-time.  example...

defined MOLECULE struct differently since you want 3D array of struct, no need to define members x, y, z.  You need to decide what members will define *your actual* `struct`.  Because I do not know, I can only guess at what characteristics you want to include in this struct illustration:

```
typedef struct  {
   char R;
   char G;
   char B;
}COLOR;

typedef struct {
     double mass;
     COLOR color;
     double size;
     char molec_formula[80];         
}CHARAC;

typedef struct {
    char name[80];
    CHARAC charac;
}MOLECULE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 4) // prog.exe <x> <y> <z>
    {
        printf("usage error, exiting");
        return 0;
    }

    int x = atoi(argv[1]);//could also use strtol() here as well
    int y = atoi(argv[2]);
    int z = atoi(argv[3]);

    // from MOLECULE definition above:

    MOLECULE molArray[x][y][z];//now you have an 3D array of a struct using VLA 
    ...(more code)
```

So, if your program name was `prog.exe`, and you wanted a 3D array with dimensions: `10, 12, 13`. then typing this on command line:

```
prog 10 12 13
```

Will result in creating  `molArray[10][12][13]`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how it would if i needed a MOLECULE molArray[x][y][z] ? and x,y,z is a dinamic value which i enter in the beginning of the program?

Comment: @RubensSerrone  - See edited section in answer above using a [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).  The advantage here is simplification of creating a multiple dimensioned array by avoiding having to use `calloc`, and then having to `free()` each element when done.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a different approach instead of using command line arguments, as suggested in the previous answer.

You can take user input using file input indirection to stdin, which can be a convenient way of processing data. Your command line call looks like:

```
./your_prog < data
```

Where `data` is a data file with a set of three space separated values on each line:

```
1 1 1
2.1 2.2 2.3
3.1 3.2 3.3
```

You could then process the data using something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct vector {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} Vector;

Vector *createVector(double x, double y, double z);

int main()
{
    // Initialize an array of pointers to Vector
    Vector **array = calloc(5, sizeof(*array));

    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    size_t lineCount = 0;
    while(1) {
        // Take input from stdin
        ssize_t r = scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &x, &y, &z);
        if (r == EOF) {
            // No more data so finish
            break;
        }

        // Note that you need to check the size of the array
        // and resize using realloc() as necessary within this loop.
        // The array needs to have space for at least lineCount + 1 elements.
        // Check this and reallocate before trying to add a
        // new element to the array.    
        array[lineCount] = createVector(x, y, z);
        lineCount++;
    }
       
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        // Do something with each element of the array
        printf("Vector %zu: (%lf, %lf, %lf)\n", i, array[i]->x, array[i]->y, array[i]->z);
    }

    // You have dynamically allocated memory, so it should be freed.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}

// Create a pointer to a Vector, dynamically allocating memory and returning
// a pointer to the new array.
Vector *createVector(double x, double y, double z)
{
    Vector *v = calloc(1, sizeof(*v));
    v->x = x;
    v->y = y;
    v->z = z;
    return v;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the problem.

```
    typedef struct
{
    double x,y,z;
}vetor;

vetor ***p;


void alloc(int lx, int lz)

{   int i,j=0;
    int ly=lx;

    p=calloc(lx,sizeof(vetor**));

    for(i=0;i<lx;i++)
    {

        p[i]=calloc(lx,sizeof(vetor*));

        for (j=0;j<lx;j++)
        {
             p[i][j]=calloc(lz,sizeof(vetor));



        }
    }
}
```

I was using sizeof(double*) but the member p is a vetor struct type.
So with this i can make a member p[a][b][c] dynamically using pointers and let it a global member ( in my code i have to) and put the values a,b and c on terminal.

I would like to thank you for the answers which makes me think a lot about this problem. Thank you for attention too.

Comment: Now, if you accept your answer it will award you points.